# Write a function that imports data and calculates summary statistics by variable conditions and writes output files

Tags: r, function, import, statistics

So initially I had the following object:

```
> head(gs)
  year disturbance lek_id  complex tot_male
1 2006           N     3T  Diamond        3
2 2007           N     3T  Diamond       17
3 1981           N   bare 3corners        4
4 1982           N   bare 3corners        7
5 1983           N   bare 3corners        2
6 1985           N   bare 3corners        5
```

With that I computed general statistics: n, min, max, mean, and sd of **tot_male** for **year within complex**. I then merged these by year within complex into a single dataset using the following:

```
gsnew <- gs %>% group_by(year, complex) %>%
summarise(n = length(tot_male), male_min = min(tot_male), male_max = max(tot_male), male_mean = mean(tot_male), male_sd = sd(tot_male))
```

Resulting in:

```
> gsnew
Source: local data frame [119 x 7]
Groups: year [?]

    year  complex     n male_min male_max male_mean   male_sd
   (int)   (fctr) (int)    (int)    (int)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1   1967  Diamond     2       33      101 67.000000 48.083261
2   1969  Diamond     2       29       69 49.000000 28.284271
3   1970 3corners     1       26       26 26.000000        NA
4   1970  Diamond     4        3       51 26.250000 21.093048
5   1971 3corners     3        6       22 12.333333  8.504901
```

How would I instead write a general function in the following format

```
FunctionName=function(Argument1,...,ArgumentN) {Statement1,...,StatementN}
• Argument1-N are any variable from object(s) • Statement1-N are any valid R statements
```

That allows me to:
• Import the data
• Select from the data a **specified year** for which statistics are desired;
• Calculate **mean, 2SD, n, and 90% Confidence Interval** for the **specified year within lek complex**
• Write the yearly-based output as a separate *.csv file

```
year complex     mean     st.dev2  n   lo90ci    hi90ci 
2007 3corners    26.28571 52.04760 7  -393.50827 446.07970 
2007 Blue        18.87500 20.15476 8  -40.00856  77.75856 
2007 book_cliffs 4.50000  13.19091 6  -24.62443  33.62443 
2007 Diamond     13.25000 48.83431 20 -205.38461 231.88461
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, I think you're pretty close. It might look something like this:

```
read_write = function(file_name, this_year) {
  file_name %>%
  read.csv %>%
  filter(year == this_year) %>%
  summarise(n = length(tot_male), 
            male_min = min(tot_male), 
            male_max = max(tot_male), 
            male_mean = mean(tot_male), 
            male_sd = sd(tot_male),
            male_2sd = 2*male_sd,
            male_upper_bound = male_mean + 1.645*male_sd,
            male_lower_bound = male_mean - 1.645*male_sd) %>%
  write.csv("out_" %>% paste0(filename), row.names = false)
  }
```

Comment: If you are worried about minutiae, you can modify 1.645 to be a t-score based on sample-size instead of a z-score

Comment: Thanks for helping me get this set up! Quite new to writing functions as this is my first endeavor. After more time than I care to mention, I managed to tweak your provided format until it was functional (see below if interested).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bramtayl

Here is the final code:

```
> library(dplyr)
> annualleksummary = function(x1) {
+   x1 %>%
+   read.csv %>% 
+   filter(tot_male, year == 2007) %>% group_by(year, complex) %>%
+   summarise(n = length(tot_male), 
+             male_min = min(tot_male), 
+             male_max = max(tot_male), 
+             male_mean = mean(tot_male), 
+             male_sd = sd(tot_male),
+             male_2sd = 2*male_sd,
+             male_upper_bound = male_mean + 1.645*male_sd,
+             male_lower_bound = male_mean - 1.645*male_sd) %>%
+   write.csv("2007_" %>% paste0(x1), row.names = F) 
+   }
> annualleksummary("gsg_leks.csv")
```

Comment: Cool! If you want to keep the ability to have this_year as a function argument, you could the last line with `write.csv(this_year %>% as.character %>% paste(x1, sep = "_"), row.names = F)`